# How do I use SampleGrabber to build a spectrum/visualizer for audio?

Tags: c#, filter, directshow

I am currently building an application that uses the DS sdk, and I need to figure out how to obtain the amplitude constantly from the audio source to draw a visualizer or spectrum of some sort.  I've been trying to look on how sample grabber is implemented on audio, but all of the information I've found have been outdated, and unhelpful.  After a few dozen attempts, this is what I have currently:

```
        ISampleGrabber pGrabber = (ISampleGrabber)pSampleGrabber;
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pInfinitePinTeeFilterAudio, "Output3"), GetPin(pSampleGrabber, "Input"), null);
        checkHR(hr, "1040");
        if (hr < 0) return false;
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pSampleGrabber, "Output"), GetPin(pNullRenderer, "In"), null);
        checkHR(hr, "1041");
        if (hr < 0) return false;

        AMMediaType media = new AMMediaType();
        media.formatType = FormatType.WaveEx;
        pGrabber.GetConnectedMediaType(media); //gets and sets media type into media

        pGrabber.SetBufferSamples(true);
        int cbbuffer = 0;
        hr = pGrabber.GetCurrentBuffer(ref cbbuffer, IntPtr.Zero);
```

How do I read what is on the current buffer, and continuously read what is on the buffer?

Comment: do you have a working graph other than figuring out how to get samples from the Sample Grabber?

Comment: Yes, my graph is completely working.  If the information is needed, I have a graph that takes a source from a network, and plays it locally.  It is as followed:  Source->demux->audio/video decoders->inf pin tees->renderers. The graph also works with the sample grabber attached.  I tried playing around with samplegrabberCB, but there seems to be only two functions of relevance:  SampleCB and BufferCB, buth of which I can't find much documentation on.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, you need to implement a callback function that the sample grabber can use, that's what [SampleCB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd376987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is for, the C# equivalent would be something like this:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.SampleCB(double SampleTime, IMediaSample pSample )
{
    //work with audio sample here
    return 0;
}
```

Also make sure that you have an audio decoder before your sample grabber in your graph, otherwise you will receive compressed samples.

There's also a relevant article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SampleGrabber.aspx) that might help you.