# How can I play only a specific audio channel and mute the rest in DirectShow.NET?

Tags: c#, audio, directshow, directshow.net

I'm trying to play a AVI file with multi-channel audio.
How can I mute or play specific channels using DirectShow.NET ?

Is there a way to do this using the existing DirectShow filter interfaces or is there a 3rd party filter that can do this ?

Comment: You need a third party filter to cut one channel out of the stream.

Comment: Thanks Roman. Would you happen to know of any filters that can do this ?

Comment: It is fairly simple to do, but I am not aware of anything ready out of the box. Another option you have is to capture with Sample Grabber and zero the channel you don't want in the streamed buffers.

Comment: Roman, could you mention how to do this using SampleGrabber ? Considering there are four channels with a 16bit sample.

Comment: See [How do I use SampleGrabber to build a spectrum/visualizer for audio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595165/how-do-i-use-samplegrabber-to-build-a-spectrum-visualizer-for-audio) on how to capture audio with Sample Grabber, there are other posts as well. You have data coming in 8 byte chunks: { `CH1-lo`, `CH1-hi`, `CH2-lo`, `CH2-hi`, `CH3-lo`, `CH3-hi`, `CH4-lo`, `CH4-hi` }. So you can just zero the bytes for channels you don't need.

Comment: I'm getting alternating data lengths of 16384 & 2816 with GetActualDataLength(). Is the 2816 sized sample a WaveFormat ? I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Could you please post a code sample on how I can achieve muting with SampleCB ? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need combine all channels into one and specify `WaveFormatExtensible` instead of `WaveFormatEx` because you need to specify the mask of an output channels. Sample grabber way will works if you receive less or same number of channels which require to output: example - you receive stereo and you need to output into rear or center channel - this way not works as you can't change type in sample grabber, but output into left or right channel will works fine.

You can use my directshow sample filter which performing that functionality, you can find it here: [Pure .NET DirectShow Filters in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421167/Pure-NET-DirectShow-Filters-in-Csharp)